# How to create a black mask from transparent image

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have a transparent image
[transparent image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3VPL.png)

I tried use Pillow convert("L") but it doesn't get all the pixels inside the rounded rectangle.

I want to create a mask like this ( include all pixels inside the rounded rectangle)
[mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJliB.png)

Comment: You haven't shared your original image. Instead you have shared a picture of it overlaid on a chessboard.

Comment: my bad, i just updated the original file

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you appear to be to be starting off with a particularly poorly designed image. If we separate it into its RGBA channels, (R on the left, A on the right) with a yellow background, we see:

[image]

So, realistically, your only hope of salvaging something useful is the alpha (A) channel:

[image]

With PIL, that's `getchannel('A')`.

Let's fill starting from each of the 4 corners and the first column halfway down the left edge with red using *"flood fill"*:

[image]

With PIL, that's `ImageDraw.floodfill()`.

Now make everything that is not red become black:

[image]

That's easiest with Numpy. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546955/2836621).

Now make everything that is not red become white:

[image]

That's easiest with Numpy.

And make everything that is red become white:

[image]

That's easiest with Numpy.